# MongoOperations save function not working properly

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using Sprind Data MongoDb, MongoTemplate and MongoOperations for saving on my data into the MongoDB. 
Everything is working fine, there is no error or exception, but still the data is not inserted into the database. I am using MongoOperations' save method to save the data.

Here is relavant part my pom.xml

```
            <properties>
                <spring.version>4.2.8.RELEASE</spring.version>
                <springsecurity.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</springsecurity.version>
                <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
                <commons.fileupload.version>1.3.1</commons.fileupload.version>
                <commons.io.version>2.4</commons.io.version>
                <springsocial.version>1.1.0.RELEASE</springsocial.version> 
            </properties>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.version}</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.4.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
```

Here is my DBOPerations class

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;

import com.bng.monitor.config.MongoConfig;
import com.bng.monitor.model.User;
//import org.springframework.context.support.GenericXmlApplicationContext;

public class DbOperations {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // For XML
    //ApplicationContext ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext("SpringConfig.xml");

    // For Annotation
    ApplicationContext ctx =
             new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MongoConfig.class);
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");

    User user = new User("kv", "password123");

    // save
    mongoOperation.save(user);

    // now user object got the created id.
    System.out.println("1. user : " + user);

    // query to search user
    Query searchUserQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("username").is("kv"));

    // find the saved user again.
    User savedUser = mongoOperation.findOne(searchUserQuery, User.class);
    System.out.println("2. find - savedUser : " + savedUser);

    // update password
    mongoOperation.updateFirst(searchUserQuery,
                         Update.update("password", "new password"),User.class);

    // find the updated user object
    User updatedUser = mongoOperation.findOne(searchUserQuery, User.class);

    System.out.println("3. updatedUser : " + updatedUser);

    // delete
    mongoOperation.remove(searchUserQuery, User.class);

    // List, it should be empty now.
    List<User> listUser = mongoOperation.findAll(User.class);
    System.out.println("4. Number of user = " + listUser.size());

    }

}
```

Here is my model class

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document(collection = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password){
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return this.username;
    }

    public void sePassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String gePassword(){
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

And Here is my output when i run the DBOperations class

> 367 [main] INFO org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5d6f64b1: startup date [Thu Nov 17 16:41:10 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
>   Collections exists? : false
>   1. user : com.bng.monitor.model.User@342c38f8
>   2. find - savedUser : null
>   3. updatedUser : null
>   4. Number of user = 0

Can anybody tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: Can you strip out all the other calls in the db operation and just try save ? Also please post the relevant part of the pom. its easier for somebody who wants to help you.

Comment: @Veeram. Tried the same. No luck.

Comment: Please update the post based on previous comment.

Comment: Done the changes...

Comment: I tried all the operations you mentioned in your class. All of them worked fine. May be you can add your Mongo Config and check that your user has correct access to the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with  User.java.

1. The constructor of the entity class needs to be annotated with @PersistenceConstructor.

> @PersistenceConstructor is used to mark the constructor which is to be used for creating entities when fetching data from the Mongo Server.

2. The name of the collection as specified in User.java was wrong:

`@Document(collection = "users")`

So, when i changed the collection name to "user", all worked fine.

```
@Document(collection = "user")
```